# Login Activity in Retrofit library in android

Tags: android, retrofit

this is my login api i want to login the app.

```
 private void attemptLogin(final String email,final String password) {

     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
             .build();
     LoginApi service = retrofit.create(LoginApi.class);
     final User user = new User();
     user.setEmail(email);
     user.setPassword(password);

     final Call<List<User>> userCall = service.login(email,password);
             userCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
             @Override
              public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {

             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Fail to login ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

     });
 }
 }
```

> http://192.168.1.14/shop/api2/login.php?email=xxxxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxxxx

Comment: What's the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: whats is the problem?. I didn't see anything wrong in code

Comment: You shared a link which has local base URL, How would I check and what problem you are facing?

Comment: please specify your problem .

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines in **`build.gradle`** file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

Create a public interface for your api params:

eg.  `@POST("api/auth")`

```
Call<Auth> auth(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

private void executeAuthEndpoint() {

    String _loginId = loginId.getText().toString();
    String _password = password.getText().toString();
    if (_loginId.length() > 0 && _password.length() > 0) {

        endpoint.auth(_loginId, _password).enqueue(new Callback<Auth>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Auth> call, Response<Auth> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                   // your code
                }
                else if (response.body()!=null && response.body().getMessage()!=null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.message_auth_fail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Auth> call, Throwable t) {
                if (call.isExecuted()) return;

                ErrorHandler.handleError(getActivity(), t);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.message_empty_field, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```